# Make multiple nodejs applications dependent on a single node.dll or libnode.dylib?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dll, native, executable

I may be fundamentally misunderstanding, but **I'd like to package several separate node executable files with just one copy of the node library by including the node library outside the executable file**, like what Electron does.

All solutions I can find for packaging node applications package `nodejs` itself into the executable, so in a case where I need 2 separate node executables, the increase in the size of a users download goes up quite dramatically (~20mb).

I can't find any way to share the node library once between multiple executables, and I do actually need multiple executables for reasons outside my control.

**Is there any way to turn my JavaScript applications into small executables and rely on the external library for node?**

---

### Windows

[image]

---

### Mac

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for your problem is when you are compiling the node packages, compile all of your code into a single executable, Then make a factory interface for running each your application when the related command line argument is passed,

See the code below,

```
const app = require('./app');

const arg = process.argv[2];

const app1 = 'app1';
const app2 = 'app2';
const app3 = 'app3';

const logger = new Logger('app-main');

switch (arg) {

    case app1:
        app.startApp1();
        break;

    case app2:
        app.startApp2();
        break;

    case app3:
        app.startApp3();
        break;

    default:
        logger.err('Invalid Argument ' + arg);

}
```

The code of the application won't be very large in size. This strategy might be perfect if each compiled applications are related with each other.

But otherwise, You may need to ship only your code and build your own runtime with nodejs and ship it to the user before installing the original all. So that way you can have a universal runtime bundle as electron.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Unfortunately I need separate executable files. Can you expand on "You may need to ship only your code and build your own runtime"?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Can you be more precise?

Comment: sorry its de-compiling, that means seeing your source code

Comment: Not possible in my use case, but if you could link to or explain whatever you have in mind that might help nonetheless.